# Issue with touchscreen functionality in Android

Tags: android, touchscreen

I am trying to get touchscreen functionality. I want to perform some actions based on whether 
user touches the screen up or down.

Here is my code for this

```
public class Sankhyaki extends Activity  implements OnTouchListener, OnKeyListener  {

float x = 0, y = 0;

public static final String TAG="Sankhayaki";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sankhyaki);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sankhyaki, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me)
{

    x = me.getX();
    y = me.getY();


    switch ( me.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        System.out.println("\n ACTION DOWN");
        Log.i(TAG, "DOWN");
        Log.i(TAG,"DOWN");
        Log.i(TAG, "x = " + x + "y = " + y );
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    System.out.println("\n ACTION UP");
        Log.i(TAG, "UP");
        Log.i(TAG, "x = " + x + "y = " + y );


        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    System.out.println("\n ACTION MOVE");
        Log.i(TAG, "MOVE");
        Log.i(TAG, "x = " + x + "y = " + y );
        break;              

    }


    return false;
 }

}
```

While running it on Emulator, When I click on the screen I
dont see any message in the LogCat or Console. I am not sure if I am doing any thing wrong.
just because I am not seeing any Log message in Logcat or Console,
 it looks like control is not going in the switch case.

There is no way I validate whether I am doing it right or not.

I want to put more code in the switch case only after I am
sure that control goes in the switch case which is not happening here,

Any  information here would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your activity as a listener. First of all, in your XML layout file, you need an id for the root view: android:id="@+id/your_view"

In youer onCreate() method, write this:

```
View v=findViewById(R.id.your_view); 
v.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Err yeah, this is actually better in this case as he has already implemented the OnTouchListener interface in his activity. good call ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly register touch event handlers on the appropriate views...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

You will need to set it on the appropriate View item from your layout..

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.whateverView);
v.setOnTouchListener(new onTouchListener()
{
    public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        //handle the event
    }
 });
```